# Javascript Regular expression to wrap unquoted JSON Values and Keys with double quotes

Tags: javascript, json, regex

There is a string:

```
const str = "[{test1: 1, test2: {test3: 2, test4: { date: 2018-08-31T21:00:00+00:00 }, place: place place, time: 21:00, ...}}]"
```

How to make a valid object from it with RegEx?
I tried the following:

```
str.replace(/:\s/g, ':').replace(/(['"])?(([а-яА-ЯЁёa-zA-Z0-9%\+\-\s_\$]+):([а-яёА-ЯЁa-zA-Z0-9%{}\+\-\s\:]+))(['"])?\s*/gi, '"$3":"$4"');
```

But this code does not allow for nesting.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - the string should be generated correctly in the first place, rather than post processed. It's better to focus on that.

Comment: Regex aren't made for JSON parsing. How are you getting that JSON?